# Use Instances Names to create custom render file names

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to render many frames of a character with different accessories and characteristics, I would like to give each image the name of these characteristics which I am instancing with the geometry node.

I was wondering if there is a way to "extract" the list of the particles and name each rendered keyframe after that. The rendering is random, so there is no real sequence on it. For example in the image attached it would be legs2-hat1-arm3.png or legs2hat1arm3.png or L2H1A3, something like this. Is it possible? [image: Spreadsheet of the objects]